# ASP.Net VB: Need a better alternative to using public shared variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I've been developing an application at work for ASP.net using VB, and we're in the stage where multiple users are now testing the application simultaneously.  While developing the application I created a class containing functions for accessing an API, and then several webforms with their own classes.  Within the API class, I declared a dozen or so public shared variables so that the webforms and API classes can easily share and access data, which worked fine while initially testing it by myself, but now as other people are using it, I'm running into issues where User X will perform a search and have results saved to a shared variable declared in the API class, and when User Y comes to use the page afterwards and searches, their search results are showing up mixed in with the results from User X.

What would be a better way to handle the variables so that they are unique to each user?  I had tried making them public shared variables in the class of the webform, but then I had issues where the values were being reset and lost on postback.

Is there anyway to make a class that can be used to store the variables thats unique to each user or session and expires after a certain amount of time?

Comment: If you create a new instance of that class like all code should do? Then you not have any issues. You can't use a global wide static class - that is global to the application - not users. However, if for each user you create  new instance of a class object, then that object will only apply to each individual users. Of course given that web pages are state-less, then like all variables - they will go out of scope. So in that cases, you need to use ViewState, or session() to persist any values or variables on a per user bases. For simple variables then hidden fields on a page can be used.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need session variables, which are unique to each user.

To write a session variable:

```
Session("MySessionVariableName") = lblMyLabel.Text
```

To read the session variable:

```
lblMyLabel.Text = Session("MySessionVariableName")
```

The stored values expire when the user's session expires.

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178581(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new instance of that class like all code should do? Then you not have any issues.

You can't use a global wide static class - that is global to the application - not users.

However, if for each user you create new instance of a class object, then that object will only apply to each individual users.

Of course given that web pages are state-less, then like all variables - they will go out of scope after the page has been rendered and sent down to the client side (browser).

So in these cases, to persist values?

You can use hidden fields or controls on the form to persist values.

You can have parameters in the URL - you often see this on say Amazon.com - they put the values RIGHT in the URL - and you can see them! (but this can often be a security issue for sensitive values - since the user can modify and mess with those parameters in the URL).

For a per page persisting, then I HIGH recommend to use ViewState.

And for global (per user) then I high recommend to use session() to persist values. However, you want to be VERY careful with session(). Say you about to buy a house on-line. And you put the PK or ID of the house you are about to buy in session(). The problem then is if the user opens a 2nd page, another browser, or even a new tab? The session() values are GLOBAL to the user. So now if they have two pages open - the PK ID you shoved into session() will be the LAST page you opened. If they go back to another browser copy that is displaying say a different house - if they click "purchase" and you use session("HousePKID"), then you get the last session() value. (and wind up buying the wrong house!!!).

So:

Session()  - global values - per user - works great.

ViewState() - per user, but ALSO LIMITED to per page.

so, just keep in mind and be aware that JUST like your current issue (static class - shared by ALL users), keep in mind that session() is great for passing values to another web page/form, but keep in mind that session() is global per user.

So, often I will use session() to PASSS values to another page, but on that new page, I will transfer the values (or class) to ViewState, and thus this design will allow multiple pages to work + function.

So, like all code - including desktop code? You can (and even should) create and use instances of custom classes you make - but they sure as the heck better not be static classes, and you have to persist such classes in ViewState, session().

As noted, for simple values, you can also use hidden controls on a web page, and shove values into such controls - they also persist.

In fact the learning curve and skill in asp.net will MUCH depend on your experience, and over time you figure out which is the best choice.

I had a few pages, and I started out using session() - its easy, works great. But JUST keep in mind that session() is global to the one user, and thus in cases in which you say store some product ID key or some such? Then think about if that application or user MIGHT have multiple browsers or tabs open. If that value is specific to the one page in question, then you better transfer that value from session() to ViewState - since ViewState is per page - not per user scoped.

For example, I have a class with a bunch of values - the user does ALL kinds of things on one page, and then I need to transfer those values to the next page.

So, I do this:

```
    ' set up PortalComp - context

    Dim MyProjectInfo As New clsProjectInfo

    With btn.Attributes
        MyProjectInfo.PortalComp = .Item("PortalComp")
        MyProjectInfo.ContactID = NzN(.Item("ContactNameID"), .Item("BillOrderBy"))
        MyProjectInfo.ContactGeneralID = .Item("ContactGeneralID")
        MyProjectInfo.QuoteNum = .Item("QuoteNum")
        MyProjectInfo.ProjectHeaderID = .Item("ProjectHeaderID")
    End With
    Session("MyProjectInfo") = MyProjectInfo
    Response.Redirect("ProjectUpload", False)
```

So we load up that class object with the values - stuff into session().

Now, in the target page, in on-load, I do this:

```
   If IsPostBack = False Then

     ' copy project info to local view state
     ViewState("Pinfo") = Session("Pinfo")
     cPinfo = Session("Info")   ' form level instances
   Else
        cPinfo = ViewState("Pinfo")
   End if
```

So, now at this point, I have class cPinfo available for ANY and all code, and all code events on this web page.

So how you use a class in vb.net, c#, and for desktop programs or the web is quite much the same. The only real issue is that you have to persist such values, since all web pages are considered state-less. That means that the web page is rendered, sent to the client side browser, and NOW THE SERVER SIDE PAGE INSTANCE DOES NOT EXIST any more!!! - it is tossed out - goes out of scope. So each new post-back starts that web page from 100% scratch. But controls on the page, ViewState and session() all do persist - but you STILL must think in terms of that web page as going OUT of scope each time it is used - it is state-less. So all code variables ONLY exist during the post-back and round trip of the browser. Once code behind runs, page is rendered - then sent back down to client and the server side page is GONE - all variables and code in that web page now go out of scope - they are gone!! (except for ViewState, session(), and of course controls on that page that automatic support viewstate (this is done automatic for you - so most controls like text box, check box etc. do automatic save their state - but NOT code behind - it runs like a sub call, and once done, all values in code are again gone and out of scope.

So, variables in code SIMPLY DOES NOT persist in web land.

Hence, you need to use ViewState, or session() to persist any values or variables on a per user bases. For simple variables then hidden fields on a page can be used.

So, ONLY use session() for values that are global to ONE user, and as noted, if the values in question are to be important - and apply to ONE web page with things like product ID etc., then you can still use session() to pass values, but you BETTER right quick transfer values from Session() to ViewState, or to some hidden controls on that form, since as I pointed  out, session() is global to the one user - and thus important values or selections made on previous pages? You can transfer via session() to that target/next page, but you BETTER then pull any values from Session into that page viewstate, and viewstate as noted is BOTH per user, and per page.

So a basic grasp of 3 things is required in asp.net

Each web page (and code behind class) is state-less. The values in that page do not exist. Keep in mind that these web pages really do NOT exist in memory on the server side - they are ONLY rendered, code behind runs (to modify controls on the page), the page is sent to client side browser and THEN THE PAGE IS TOSSED OUT server side!!!

Those web pages are state-less. And while controls on such pages that have view state enabled do persist, your vb.net values and variables do not. you start from scratch EACH time the user clicks on a button.

And last but not least - session() is global per user, and Viewstate() is per user per web page.

Keep all of above in mind, and you should be fine.